# Return class object or no object

Tags: java

```
public static Attendant askForAtt() {
    Scanner scanAtt = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random randAtt = new Random();
    Attendant asnAtt;
    System.out.println("Do you require an attendant? Y or N");
    String response = scanAtt.next();
    if ((response.equals("yes")) || (response.equals("Yes"))) {
        // Cars.setAssignedTo(myAtt.get(randAtt.nextInt(myAtt.size())));
        asnAtt = myAtt.get(randAtt.nextInt(myAtt.size()));
    } else if ((response.equals('n')) || (response.equals('N')) || (response.equals("no")) || (response.equals("No"))) {
        asnAtt = new Attendant("User");
    }

    return asnAtt;
    //return myAtt.get(randAtt.nextInt(myAtt.size()));
}
```

So I have a function in a garage class to create a car with parameters. One of the parameter is an attendant class if a user want one.

```
public Cars(String carID, String plateNum, String position, Attendant assignedTo, long currTime) {
    this.carID = carID;
    this.plateNum = plateNum;
    Cars.position = position;
    Cars.assignedTo = assignedTo;
    this.currTime = currTime;
}
```

So I have to return an attendant which I can't. I'm thinking that it is the null in the beginning of the method, but java is telling me to initialize it and i don't know with what.
    Also if the user type No then I'm currently returning another type of attendant called user.
    Is there a way to return nothing because right now I had to create another attendant called user(which does not make sense) and I can't create a user class just for that.

I have a part of the garage class just below if you need 
    please help me...
    I'm stuck and can't find the solution.

creating cars here:

```
public void addCar() {
    Cars car = new Cars(Cars.getID(), Cars.askCarID(), Cars.getPosition(), Attendant.askForAtt(), System.currentTimeMillis());
    myGarage.add(car);
    //System.out.println(car);
}
```

Comment: you can initialized Attendant asnAtt=null why not?

Comment: I get an error if i put null

Comment: which error? exception or compiler error?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Garage.toString(Garage.java:56)
 at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.PrintStream.println(Unknown Source)
 at Main.main(Main.java:19)

Comment: you have to handle null check at Garage class toString method

Comment: If you are unsure if your Attendant will be created or not, you can try using an Optional<Attendant> . You can read about it here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java8-optional-2175753.html

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this in your `askForAtt` method

```
 public static Attendant  askForAtt() {
        Scanner scanAtt = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random randAtt = new Random();
        Attendant  asnAtt = null;
        System.out.println("Do you require an Attendant ? Y or N");
        String response = scanAtt.next();
        if ((response.equalsIgnoreCase(("yes")))) {
            // Cars.setAssignedTo(myAtt.get(randAtt.nextInt(myAtt.size())));
            return myAtt.get(randAtt.nextInt(myAtt.size()));
        } else if ((response.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) || (response.equalsIgnoreCase("no"))) {
            return new Attendant ("User");
        }
        return new Attendant ("User");    //If input is neither Yes nor No then return new Attendant    
    }
```